# Comparing elements in a list in order using loop or stack/queue

Tags: python, list, loops, queue, stack

I have a list `ls` with integer elements between 0 and 100. I want to build a function that counts a number of elements until it encounters an element that has a larger value, and appends the count to the solution list.

In other words, if `ls = [5, 10, 1, 1, 20, 1]`, the solution should be `[1, 3, 2]`:

- `1` comes from the first element, `5`
- `3` comes from the second to fourth elements, `10, 1, 1`
- `2` comes from the last two elements, `20, 1`

(If `ls = [7, 3, 9]`, the return should be `[2,1]`.)

I used a `for` loop to perform the task:

```
def compare_and_count(ls):
    answer = []
    num = 1
    ref = 0
    for j in range(1, len(ls)):
        try:
            if ls[ref + j] <= ls[ref]:
                num += 1
            else:
                answer.append(num)
                num = 1
                ref = ref + j
        except IndexError:
            break
    answer.append(num)
    return answer
```

I tried to do a value comparison with two movable references, but this raises `IndexError` and also sometimes neglects the final counting and hence returns an incorrect list. (I added `try...except` to be free of the `IndexError`, but the latter problem is still unsolved)

I assume either `loop` or `stack/queue` is the most concise way to solve this, but I couldn't land an optimal way yet. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just add a check 'if (ref < len(ls) - j) :... '

Comment: @SamarthBhatia not quite sure what you're referring to; do you mean another `if` loop should be added on top of the current `for` loop?

Comment: I've written it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited the answer to correct it .

```
def my(a):
    count = 1
    maxval = a[0]
    answer = []
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        if a[i] > maxval:
            maxval = a[i]
            answer.append(count)
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1
    answer.append(count)
    return answer
```

> I tried to do a value comparison with two movable references

You dont need to, just one moving index `i` and one `count` counter with a `maxval` to check the condition.

Comment: while this may take care of the `IndexError`, this neglects some element comparisons throughout some occasions. I've run a couple of test cases I've mentioned, and when `ls = [5, 10, 1, 1, 20, 1]`, the return is `[1, 2, 1]` instead of the expected `[1, 3, 2]`.